# How to make List from DbContext.Table in C# with EntityFrameworkCore Code-First without errors?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

Here is the line of code where the error is spotted:

```
DT.ItemsSource = context.Citizen.ToList();
```

Error: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Invalid column name 'LicenseID'."

There's class from table Citzen:

```
    public class Citizen
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int? LicenseId { get; set; }
            public string Name {get; set;}
            public string Surame { get; set; }
            public string Patronymic { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public string Concact_Details { get; set; }
            public virtual DriversLicense license { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        }
```

The same problems I have in with  DatabaseContext:

```
        public class MyDbContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<DriversLicense> DriversLicence { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Citizen> Citizen { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Operation> Operation { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Administration> Administration { get; set; }
            public DbSet<HeadQuaters> HeadQuaters {get;set;}

            public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
 modelBuilder.Entity<Citizen>(entity => {

                    entity.Property(e => e.LicenseId).HasColumnName("LicenseID");

                    entity.HasOne(d => d.license).WithMany(p => p.Citizens).HasForeignKey(d => d.LicenseId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
                });
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You model configuration told EF that the database table has a column named 'LicenseID'

```
entity.Property(e => e.LicenseId).HasColumnName("LicenseID");
```

But that column doesn't actually exist on your SQL Sever table

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Invalid column name
> 'LicenseID'."

So look at the table, and map the property to the correct column.